# Problema de concurrencia Wildfly 10 Primefaces 6 en com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase/doPhase

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, rendimiento, wildfly

He desarrollado una aplicacion JEE con primefaces 6 Spring en Wildfly 10.

La aplicación funciona bien con poco usuarios, pero a partir de 10 usuarios el sistema empieza a dar unos tiempos de respuesta muy altos de mas de 10 segundos. Con 25 Usuario da tiempos de 30 segundos

El servidor está sobrado de recursos, le sobra CPU y Memoria RAM. La JVM está bien configurada y le sobra memoria también.

Si embargo hay ciertas páginas que hace que la fase de renderizado de JSF sea muy lento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La aplicación básicamente tiene 3 pantallas, las cuales se generan con un template y varios ui:composition que se crean con iu:include.

¿Podrían estar generando interbloqueos entre estas paginas .xhtml que utilizan los mismos iu:includes, a la hora del renderizado?

Un ejemplo de una de las páginas es:

```
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                template="/WEB-INF/template_amt/template_amt.xhtml">

   <ui:define name="content">
        <h:outputScript name="jquery/jquery.js" library="primefaces" target="head"/> 
        <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-12 ui-g-nopad" style="height: 55%;" >

               <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/template_amt/componentes/tabs.xhtml" /> 

        </div>
        <div class="ui-g" style="height: 205px;">
                   <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/template_amt/componentes/datos.xhtml" /> 
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-12 pie" style="height: 50px;">
                    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/template_amt/componentes/botones_abajo.xhtml" /> 
        </div>

    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Generalmente las consultas dentro de ciclos producen un rendimiento pobre, pero sin mas información es imposible responder esta pregunta.